# Trusted SSL Certificate for Backend Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, tls1.2

I'm creating a simple website. The frontend is stored in S3, and hosted by Cloudfront. I managed to add a trusted SSL certificate to my frontend domain ([www.xyz.com](http://www.xyz.com)) using AWS Certificate Manager.

The backend is running on an EC2 instance. I added a self-signed certificate to it. I'm able to hit the APIs using Postman but the requests from frontend are failing because of the self-signed certificate.

I checked the AWS Certificate Manager again if it could provide me with a cert for my backend server, but it requires a domain. My server is running on an IP and port, and I couldn't find any service that provides a certificate for an IP. I don't want to spend extra money to get a domain for my backend.

So how do I get a trusted SSL certificate for a backend server, running on something like 10.12.12.10:9000?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> couldn't find any service that provides a certificate for an IP.

This is because you need domain to obtain valid public certificate. You can't register SSL cert for an IP. But if you already have your own domain `www.xyz.com`, you can get a **certificate for its subdomain**, e.g. `api.xyz.com`.

However, ACM certs can't be used on instances. Thus, you need to get a valid public SSL cert from a **third party**. A popular choice is https://letsencrypt.org/ with `certbot` which provides free SSL certificates. By the way, StackOverlow is using letsencrypt  for its SSL cert provider, thus its widely used and trusted ssl provider.

Comment: So to use a certificate, I need to get a domain, and for the backend to be linked to that domain, it needs to be running on Port 443, right?

Comment: @ShivanshKuchhal Yes. You can setup ssl cert on your instance using nginx for instance which will act as a reverse proxy to serve https for your app.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. So what I was hoping for, is not possible. Helpful answer though.